# How can I query the parent payment record using JS. oQuery

Tags: javascript, dynamic

To check if paymenttype equal credit account **[entity form: auto_paymenttype]**

Then , if payment amount <= resit amount, it will save
else > prevent save (popup message invalid: payment amount should lower than resit amount)**[entity form: auto_resittype]**

Hi guys,
It could be great if anyone can help me on this. Basically, I have two entities which is auto_paymenttype and auto_resittype. How can I query the parent adjustment record using JS. I have provide my current code, please help me to review it. Thank you!

```js
function resitApproveAmount(executionContext) {
        try {
        const object = {};
        object.fctx = executionContext.getFormContext();
            object.saveEvent = object.fctx.getEventArgs();
            object.paymentamount = object.fctx.getAttribute("auto_paymentamount").getValue();
            object.resitamount = object.fctx.getAttribute("auto_resitamount").getValue();
            
            
        object.paymenttype = Xrm.Page.getAttribute("auto_paymenttype").getValue();
            if (object.paymenttype != null) {
                object.autoGUID = object.paymenttype[0].id.substring(1, 37);
            }
             
            Xrm.WebApi.retrieveMultipleRecords("auto_paymenttype", "$select=auto_name").then(
            function success(result) {
                  for (var i = 0; i < result.entities.length; i++) {
                  object.auto_name = result.entities[i]["auto_name"];}
                  if(object.auto_name == "Credit Account"){
                  if (object.paymenttamount >= object.resitamount) {
                    alert("Payment Amount cannot be more than Resit Amount.");
                    object.saveEvent.preventDefault();
                    } 
                else 
                    {object.fctx.data.save();}
                       }
                },
                    
         
                function (error) {
                    console.log(error.message);
                }
            );
        } 
        catch (error) {
            console.log(error);
        }
    }
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Visit the [help], take the [tour] to see what and [ask]. If you get stuck, post a [mcve] of your attempt, noting input and expected output using the [`[<>]`](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/358992/ive-been-told-to-create-a-runnable-example-with-stack-snippets-how-do-i-do) snippet editor. Your snippet is currently NOT a [mcve]

Comment: Post an example object and a copy of `function success(result) {` we assum the `retrieveMultipleRecords` works as expected

Comment: oQuery... Is that the Irish jQuery?